# Регулирование цены

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, как сделать вот такую штуку, может у кого пример есть как ее реализовать?[image: регулирование]

Answer (score 1):

Если не требуется поддержка старых версий IE, [то просто стандартный input](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/range):

```html
<input type="range" min="1000" max="6000" value="3000" width="100px">
```

Comment: Да, но его нельзя стилизовать

Comment: @Voprositel, можно, смотря насколько сильно это надо сделать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider

Comment: оу, спасибо, я не знал